# How do you go about getting a sponsored tag

Tags: discussion, advertising, sponsored-tags

How do you go about getting a sponsored tag and how much does it cost?  Is it a price on application sort of thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the "Advertising" link at the bottom of the page - https://stackexchange.com/about/contact :

> To buy ads or inquire about tag sponsorships, please contact us at [ads@stackoverflow.com](http://mailto:ads@stackoverflow.com), or call 646-826-3868 to reach our ad sales team.